# python/django list.reverse() and reversed(list)

Tags: python, django, list

I tried this today in my django console and I got two different results. I thought that `list.reverse()` reverses the list (ie first object becomes last and so on)[1]. However it does not seem the case.

```
>>> from django.db.models import Q
>>> q1 = Q(result=1)
>>> q2 = Q(result=-1)
>>> q3 = q1 | q2
>>> form = UserData.objects.filter(user=user).filter(coins__gt=0).filter(q3).order_by('-modified', '-placed').values_list('result', flat=True)[:10]
>>> form
Out[14]: [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1]
>>> form.reverse()
Out[15]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]
>>> form_bw = []
>>> for f in reversed(form):
...     form_bw.append(f)
...     
>>> form_bw
Out[18]: [-1, -1, 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
```

What am I doing wrong? Obviously what I want is `form_bw`

[1] http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html

Comment: You need to convert the result into a list first. `values_list` doesn't actually give you a python list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do

```
querysert.order_by('-modified', '-placed').reverse()
```

it actually means

```
querysert.order_by('modified', 'placed')
```

Thus if the result is unexpected, simply reverse in Python

```
list(reversed(values_list))
```

Or you have to check the ordering logic the `reverse` brought to the queryset.

Answer (score 4):

`form` is not a list. It's a QuerySet, which has many similarities to a list, but is not one. In particular, it defines a [`reverse` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#reverse) which actually goes back to the database to ask for the items in reverse order.

Answer (score 3):

Is `form` really a list? Note that `list.reverse` does not return a result, so your prompt results look fishy:

```
In [1]: lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
In [2]: lst.reverse()    # <-- note: no result returned here (~ None)
In [3]: lst 
Out[3]: [4, 3, 2, 1]
In [4]:
```

Also, as a side note, a nicer way to use `reversed` is:

```
In [5]: lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]

In [6]: rev = list(reversed(lst))

In [7]: rev
Out[7]: [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Alternatively, just use a slice with a negative step:

```
In [8]: rev = lst[::-1]

In [9]: rev
Out[9]: [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

Answer (score 3):

I am no Django expert and therefore am not sure what the type of `form` is. However, it's pretty clear that it's not a standard list:

```
>>> form.reverse()
Out[15]: [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1]
```

The built-in `list.reverse()` function returns `None`, whereas this `reverse()` function appears to be returning something different. This leads me to conclude that `form` is not a list.

Try the following:

```
form = list(form)
form.reverse()
```

Also note that:

```
>>> form_bw = []
>>> for f in reversed(form):
...     form_bw.append(f)
```

is just a long way of saying:

```
>>> form_bw = list(reversed(form))
```

Comment: actually, `form = list(form)` and `form.reverse()` do work. So, I guess `values_list()` in django does not return a list.

Answer (score 0):

Altough the other solutions here are correct in most of the cases but with the values_list of the Django QuerySet, it didnt work.

the only way was:

```
season_ids = matchesByLeague.values_list('season_id', flat=True).distinct()
season_ids = list(reversed(season_ids))

#Not working
#season_ids = matchesByLeague.values_list('season_id', flat=True).distinct()
#season_ids.reverse()
#season_ids = matchesByLeague.values_list('season_id', flat=True).distinct().reverse()
#reversed(list(season_ids))
```

Thanks @NPE and @xpanta